# Salesforce LiveAgent REST API 400: Request is not a valid ChatEnd - ChatEnd requires a non-null value on the reason property

Tags: python, rest, salesforce

I implemented some Python code to have my front-end interact with the SF LiveAgent REST API as documented here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.live_agent_rest.meta/live_agent_rest

Everything works fine except when I make a POST request to the `/Chasitor/ChatEnd`endpoint. Here I get a 400 with the response in the title.

To me it seems this endpoint is not thoroughly documented. It's docs (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.live_agent_rest.meta/live_agent_rest/live_agent_rest_ChatEnd.htm) says that the `ChatEndReason` body is required, but under the "Request Bodies for Live Agent REST API" there is no such body documented. Simply passing a dictionary with `reason` as is suggested in `ChatEnd`endpoint docs does not work.

Here is my code for this request:

```
import requests  

response = requests.post(
    endpoint + '/Chasitor/ChatEnd',
    headers={
            'X-LIVEAGENT-SESSION-KEY': session_info['key'], 
            'X-LIVEAGENT-AFFINITY': session_info['affinityToken'],
            'X-LIVEAGENT-API-VERSION': '46'
    },
    data=json.dumps({'reason':'client'})
)
```

`endpoint` is simply the url of my SF instance. `session_info` a dict that contains the necessary infos.
The same request to the `/Chasitor/ChatMessage` endpoint works fine (see below), as do all other requests I make. I suspect the body needs to look different, but I have no idea how.

```
response = requests.post(
    endpoint + '/Chasitor/ChatMessage',
    headers={
            'X-LIVEAGENT-SESSION-KEY': session_info['key'], 
            'X-LIVEAGENT-AFFINITY': session_info['affinityToken'],
            'X-LIVEAGENT-API-VERSION': '46'
    },
    data=json.dumps({'text': message})
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I found through trial and error that the issue was caused by the payload. There is a hint in the docs, but in my opinion it is not well documented:

> Request body:
>
> ChatEndReason—Include the ChatEndReason parameter in the
>   request body of your request to specify the reason that the chat
>   ended. This parameter is required. For example: {reason: “client”}.

The type `ChatEndReason` needs to be included in the payload. Therefore `{'type':'ChatEndReason', 'reason':'client'}` worked.